# Which of SUM(val/2) or SUM(val)/2 is better?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization, aggregate

I presume that

```
SELECT SUM(val/2) FROM my_table
```

will compute the division N times (once per row)

```
SELECT SUM(val)/2 FROM my_table
```

will compute the SUM() and then the division only once

Is that right?
For any aggregate function?

Answer (score 1):

The second is better. Performance-wise the number of operations done is lesser than in the first case. Just one division is done, while in the first N divisions are done.

Secondly, the result of the second query is more "exact" than in the first, as just one approximation will be done when the sum is divided by 2. In the first query the approximated val/2 values are sum, and then the result approximated.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but I add:  The performance difference may be only 1% -- not enough to notice.

Answer (score 0):

if dividing by 2 then both methods are correct
if the division into 3 or another number then the first method is correct

Comment: the question is actually regarding performance (how many times the division is performed)

Comment: if so then the second